# How to call C++ static function of a class using JNI for android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am doing an android application that will use a C++ library. For this reason I need to build the C++ project using Android-NDK. But the problem I am facing right now is how to call C++ static function using JNI.

In my C++ code I have a singleton class. As we all know to implement a singleton class we need to introduce static function which is responsible to create an instance of this class. Now what I need is to call the static function using JNI to create an instance that I can use into my android application.

Comment: What's the problem here?  JNI C++ methods can call static C++ methods.  Are you trying to pass the whole singleton object to Java?

Comment: Yes. How I can pass singleton object to Java?

Comment: actually what I need is to use the singleton object into android to access singleton class member functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do on JNI side:

```
long Java_mypackage_com_createSingleton(JNIEnv* env)
{
     return MySingleton::getInstance();
}

bool Java_mypackage_com_useSingletonSomehow(long singleton) 
{
      return (MySingleton*)singleton->someFunc();
}
```

In Singleton class:

```
   MySingleton* getInstance() 
    {
      if(instance_ == NULL)
      {
          instance_ = new MySingleton();
      }
      return instance_;

    }
```

On Java side:

```
package mypackage.com;

class SingletonUser
{
private long mSingletonInstance;

public SingletonUser() {
   mSingleton = createSingleton();
}

public boolean someFunc() {
   return useSingletonSomehow(mSingletonInstance);
}

private native boolean useSingletonSomehow(long instance);
private native long createSingleton();
```

}

Comment: Suppose my singleton class has a member function name Create(). So, to call the Create() function I need to call in the following way. is it right or wrong?`bool Java_mypackage_com_useSingletonSomehow(long singleton) 
{
      return (MySingleton*)singleton->Create();
}
`

Comment: Yes. JNI functions have to be C functions but you surely can call any C++ code from them.